# Bits to type from buffer

Tags: c++, c, types, binary, bit

A file which contains the buffer value. The first 16 bits contain the type. The next 32 bits gives the length of the data. The remaining value in the data.

How can I find the type from the 16 bits (find if it is int or char...)

I'm super stuck in my though process here. Not able to find a way to convert bits to types.

Comment: Doesn't your problem statement tell you how the type is encoded by the first 16 bits?

Comment: There is no single way to convert 16 bits to a 'type'. You need to explain how the type is enocded in those 16 bits, then someone will be able to tell you the C++ needed to do the conversion.

Comment: Simply read the 16 bits from the file into a 16-bit variable, such as a `uint16_t` or equivalent, then swap its endian if needed, then compare its numeric value against the values of the defined types. What is so hard about that?

Comment: The questions is : Record Type (16 bits)
Record Length (32 bits)
Record Data 
For each record, print the actual (human readable) value of the type &
length fields as integers and then each data byte as a hex value.

Comment: @RemyLebeau How is possible. Would you please give an example.

Comment: How are you reading the file to begin with? With which API? `std::(i)fstream`? `(f)read()`? Other? You tagged the question as both C and C++, but they are different languages and handle file I/O very differently. Please show the actual code that you have already tried so far that is not working for you.

Comment: I've used (f)read()

Comment: See `uint32_t` and `uint16_t`.  The `uint16_t` type is guaranteed to be 16 bits.  So if you need to read 16 bits, read one of these types; similarly for the `uint32_t` type.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have the homework assignment:

> You are given a file where the first bit encodes the type, the
> next 7 bits encode the length, and the rest is the data.
>
> The types are encoded in the following way:
>
> - `0` is for int
> - `1` is for char
>
> Print the ints or chars separated by newlines.

You just use the given information! Since 1 bit is used to encode the type there are two possible types. So you just read the first bit, then do:

```
if (bit == 0) {
    int *i = ...
}
else if (bit == 1) {
    char *c = ...
}
```